# Sorting a MySQL query with ORDER BY or with PHP sort functions

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a query that I want to sort alphabetically, but the trick is that I want the sorting to treat two columns equally.  For instance, if the first row of `first_col` equals `apple` and the second row of `second_col` equals `aardvark` I want the value in the second row of `second_col` to be listed **before** the value in the first row of `first_col`.  A value (not `NULL` or `''`) will always exist in every row of `second_col`, but the value in `first_col` can be `''`.  Hopefully I have explained this good enough.  I don't care if I have to use MySQL or PHP for this, but once sorted, the array is read through and echoed into an HTML table.  Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

This is what I have for code right now.  In my MySQL query I need `b_name` and `l_name` to be equal.  The column `b_name` does not always have a value.  When I put the values into the table it is based on the existence of `b_name`.  If `b_name` does not exist the `f_name` and `l_name` are combined to replace `b_name`.

```
                $query = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY b_name, l_name";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                mysql_close($link);

                $num = mysql_num_rows($result);                         

                for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){

                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                    $class = (($i % 2) == 0) ? "table_odd_row" : "table_even_row";

                    if($row[b_name]!=''){
                        echo "<tr class=".$class.">";

                            echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$row[c_id].">".$row[c_id]."</a></td>";
                            echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$row[c_id].">".$row[b_name]."</a></td>";
                            echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$row[c_id].">".$row[phone]."</a></td>";

                        echo "</tr>";

                    }

                    else{
                        echo "<tr class=".$class.">";

                            echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$row[c_id].">".$row[c_id]."</a></td>";
                            echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$row[c_id].">".$row[f_name]." ".$row[l_name]."</a></td>";
                            echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$row[c_id].">".$row[phone]."</a></td>";

                        echo "</tr>";

                    }


                }

            ?>      

        </table>
```

Comment: If the first row is `'a','b'` and the second row is `'b','a'` and the two columns are treated equally, which of those rows should come first and why?

Comment: Show us the query.  Generally, the only reliable way to use two columns as one for sorting requires using a UNION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys, but none of your answers allowed me to sort the data AND echo it into the HTML table correctly once sorted.  A `UNION` might have worked, but I think my solution was faster as far as figuring it all out goes.

```
                $query = "SELECT c_id, b_name, l_name, f_name, phone FROM customers";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                mysql_close($link);

                $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

                for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                    if($row[b_name]!=''){
                        $new_result[$i]['c_id'] = $row[c_id];
                        $new_result[$i]['c_name'] = $row[b_name];
                        $new_result[$i]['phone'] = $row[phone];
                    }

                    else{
                        $new_result[$i]['c_id'] = $row[c_id];
                        $new_result[$i]['c_name'] = $row[l_name].", ".$row[f_name];
                        $new_result[$i]['phone'] = $row[phone];                         
                    }
                }                       

                foreach ($new_result as $key => $row) {
                   $c_id[$key]  = $row['c_id'];
                   $c_name[$key] = $row['c_name'];
                   $phone[$key] = $row['phone'];
                }

                array_multisort($c_name, SORT_ASC, $c_id, SORT_ASC, $new_result);   

                for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){

                    $class = (($i % 2) == 0) ? "table_odd_row" : "table_even_row";

                    echo "<tr class=".$class.">";

                        echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$new_result[$i]['c_id'].">".$new_result[$i]['c_id']."</a></td>";
                        echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$new_result[$i]['c_id'].">".$new_result[$i]['c_name']."</a></td>";
                        echo "<td><a href=Edit_Customer.php?c_id=".$new_result[$i]['c_id'].">".$new_result[$i]['phone']."</a></td>";

                    echo "</tr>";                       

                }

            ?>      

        </table>
```

Comment: selecting the whole table is faster? well-well. I wish your server luck.

Comment: @Col. Sharpnel, you should take another look at the query in my answer. I am not selecting the whole table, only the fields I need.

Comment: Lol you're funny guy :) fields means nothing while rows is everything.

Comment: Please explain to me then because I do not understand what you are getting at.  To me it seems the solution I posted in my answer is a good one for me.  I need ALL the rows of the columns I selected, and I successfully sorted them with the PHP function `array_multisort` and echoed them into a table exactly as I wanted.  How is any of this bad or more stressful on a server than another alternative (which would most likely require me to restructure the database)?

Answer (score 3):

If your tables are very similar you can do this

In my case I have a table `test_a` with 2 columns `id` and `name`

```
(SELECT * FROM test_a a1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM test_a a2) 
ORDER BY name DESC
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't completely clear but you could try using this as your ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY LEAST(first_col, second_col)
```

Demonstration:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (first_col VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, second_col VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (first_col, second_col) VALUES
('a', 'b'),
('d', 'e'),
('f', 'c');

SELECT first_col, second_col
FROM table1
ORDER BY first_col, second_col;

a b
d e
f c

SELECT first_col, second_col
FROM table1
ORDER BY LEAST(first_col, second_col);

a b
f c
d e
```

Comment: This basically what I have done, but it does not work because the `first_col` is always given priority, so everything from `second_col` ends up at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @typoknig: According to your question you wrote `ORDER BY first_col, second_col`. This is not the same.

Comment: @typoknig: In general the result is not the same. I've posted some example code so you can see that this is the case.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more technical... The result is the same for me because some of the values in the `first_col` are `''` so all of those values end up at the top of the list, sorted by the value of `second_col` while all the values in the `first_col` end up sorted among themselves at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(b_name, l_name)
```

or (if your fields are NULL when EMPTY)

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(b_name, l_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

As they say above, UNION ALL is your friend, and, of course, if you have only one table, you can always do this:

```
(SELECT field1 AS name FROM TABLE1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT field2 AS name FROM TABLE1) 
ORDER BY name DESC
```

So, you are asking for two diferent rows in the same table, and ordering it as it was one.