# how will i order this query by DoctorName

Tags: php, mysql

I use this query but I don't know how will I order this by `DoctorName`?

```
$q=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from doctor where status='". $stat ."'");
```

Comment: how about ORDER BY? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a MySQL query with ORDER BY or with PHP sort functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145118/sorting-a-mysql-query-with-order-by-or-with-php-sort-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `ORDER BY` statement to your query:

```
$q=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from doctor where status='". $stat ."' ORDER BY `doctor_last_name`");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ORDER BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php) command to order by columns.

```
$q=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from doctor where status='". $stat ."' ORDER BY doctor_last_name");
```

You can add a list to the ORDER BY command to provide a hierarchy of order. Example:

`SELECT * FROM EmployeeData ORDER BY Date, LastName, FirstName;`

This command will sort by the `Date` column first. All matching dates will then be ordered by the `LastName` column. All possible records that `Date` AND `LastName` match will be ordered by the `FirstName` column and so on!